# How to edit upper heading part of emulator?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

I xml files are responsible for graphical  presentations on emulator like buttons, text box etc.
 But how to edit Upper heading part which is shown in image by arrow?
 I don't know it can be editable or not. 
I download a tutorial from internet when I run it, it shown a text on upper heading of emulator. I need to edit it. How can I do it?

[image: Emulator image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the title for each of your activities via the manifest. Within each activity tag, set the android:label attribute accordingly, specifying a string resource (as defined in your res/values/strings.xml):

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
</activity>
```

You can also set this programmatically, which will override the value specified in the manifest. Within your activity simply use the setTitle() method. For example:

```
setTitle("My title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Look Manifest file. I think that android:label in activity tag help you.